# Display the deleted code of a function

Tags: functions

I deleted the code of a function that I wrote. The function is still working fine but the code is no more available.
How can I do to display the code of the function I have written ?

**Edit:** Thanks for your answers.

「??f」    works lovely well ! it is the best.
DownValues[f] as well (but not UpValues, neither oeher **Values)

PrintDefinitions[f] as well, but requires GeneralUtilities...

Comment: Use `?? f` or `DownValues[f]` (or possibly `OwnValues[f]`, `Upvalues[f]`, and/or `SubValues[f]` etc).  The first will be easier to interpret, if you don't know how down-values work.

Comment: The simplest thing to do is perhaps to call ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]`` and then `PrintDefinitions[f]`. This will create a separate notebook with a nicely formatted code of your function. You can then select the cells with code and right-click, then use `Copy As Plain text`, and copy to a new input cell, if you want to.

Comment: Another useful function is `Language\`ExtendedDefinition`, which takes either the symbol or the symbol name as an argument, and returns *Values, `Messages` and `Attributes`.

Answer (score 4):

To remove this question from the **Unanswered**:

> The simplest thing to do is perhaps to call `` Needs["GeneralUtilities`"] `` and then `PrintDefinitions[f]`. This will create a separate notebook with a nicely formatted code of your function. You can then select the cells with code and right-click, then use `Copy As Plain text`, and copy to a new input cell, if you want to. – Leonid Shifrin Oct 19 '16 at 12:14